# selected options from radio and checkbox are not passing data

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, react-native, semantic-ui

I am trying to make a set of questions through multiple pages, so I need the selected answer from page 1 and page 2 to be passed to page 3 because page 3 is like the confirmation page which will show all the selected answer from the past 2 pages.

The interface is successfully shown, well, easy but it seems like there is no data passed at all, oh, and the types of questions are radio and checkbox, so it's kinda hard for me because these 2 types are something new for me (if textarea or normal input, is easy).

This is the *mainpage.jsx*

```
// MainForm.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AircondQuantity from './AircondQuantity';
import ServicePackage from './ServicePackage';
import Confirmation from './Confirmation';
import Success from './Success';

class MainForm extends Component {
    state = {
        step: 1,
        oneAircond: ''
    }

    nextStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state
        this.setState({
            step : step + 1
        })
    }

    prevStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state
        this.setState({
            step : step - 1
        })
    }

    handleChange = input => event => {
        this.setState({ [input] : event.target.value })
    }

    render(){
        const {step} = this.state;
        const { oneAircond } = this.state;
        const values = { oneAircond };
        switch(step) {
        case 1:
            return <AircondQuantity 
                    nextStep={this.nextStep} 
                    handleChange = {this.handleChange}
                    values={values}
                    />
        case 2:
            return <ServicePackage 
                    nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    prevStep={this.prevStep}
                    handleChange = {this.handleChange}
                    values={values}
                    />
        case 3:
            return <Confirmation 
                    nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    prevStep={this.prevStep}
                    values={values}
                    />
        case 4:
            return <Success />
        }
    }
}

export default MainForm;
```

this is the first page, *AircondQuantity.jsx*

```
// AircondQuantity.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, FormRadio, Radio } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class AircondQuantity extends Component{

    saveAndContinue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.nextStep()
    }

    render(){
        const { values } = this.props;
        return(
            <Form >
                <h1 className="ui centered"> How many aircond units do you wish to service? </h1>

                <Form.Field>
                    <Radio
                        label='1'
                        name='oneAircond'
                        value='oneAircond'
                        //checked={this.state.value === this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.props.handleChange('oneAircond')}
                        defaultValue={values.oneAircond}
                    />
                </Form.Field>

                <Button onClick={this.saveAndContinue}> Next </Button>
            </Form>
        )
    }
}

export default AircondQuantity;
```

this is the next page, *ServicePackage.jsx*

```
// ServicePackage.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Checkbox } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { throws } from 'assert';

class ServicePackage extends Component{
    saveAndContinue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    }

    back  = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    }

    render(){
        const { values } = this.props
        return(
        <Form color='blue' >
            <h1 className="ui centered"> Choose your package </h1>
            <Form.Field>
                <Checkbox 
                label={<label> Chemical Cleaning </label>} />
            </Form.Field>

            <Form.Field>
                <Checkbox 
                label={<label> Deep Cleaning </label>} />
            </Form.Field>

            <Button onClick={this.back}> Previous </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.saveAndContinue}> Next </Button>
        </Form>
        )
    }
}

export default ServicePackage;
```

this is the *confirmation.jsx* page, the page that will show all the selected options

```
// Confirmation.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, List } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import AircondQuantity from './AircondQuantity';

class Confirmation extends Component{
    saveAndContinue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    }

    back  = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    }

    render(){
        const {values: { oneAircond }} = this.props;

        return(
            <div>
                <h1 className="ui centered"> Confirm your Details </h1>
                <p> Click Confirm if the following details have been correctly entered </p>
                <List>
                    <List.Item>
                        <List.Content> Aircond Quantity: {oneAircond}</List.Content>
                    </List.Item>
                </List>

                <Button onClick={this.back}>Back</Button>
                <Button onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Confirm</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Confirmation;
```

I am **very new** in using React and I know that I have some mistakes in transferring values or variables but I can't detect it, coz I am a newbie, so em, can you help me? thank you.

Comment: I suggest you read about form handling in react: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html. your inputs are not controlled. Moreover maybe you should consider using Formik or other 3rd party library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look right to me:

```
onChange={this.props.handleChange('oneAircond')}
```

Firstly, it's going to be called instantly, before `onChange` is actually called, to fix that do this:

```
onChange={() => this.props.handleChange('oneAircond')}
```

However you'll also need to pass the change event from the radio button, try this:

```
onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange('oneAircond')(event)}
```

The `handleChange` function below is a function that returns another function, the first one taking the 'oneAircond' string (`input`) and returning a function that is expecting the `event` from the radio button to be passed which is what you're missing

```
handleChange = input => event => {
    this.setState({ [input] : event.target.value })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first i convert solution into hooks:

```
// MainForm.jsx
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AircondQuantity from './AircondQuantity';
import ServicePackage from './ServicePackage';
import Confirmation from './Confirmation';
// import Success from './Success';

let MainForm = (props) => {

const [step, setStep] = useState(1)
const [input, setInput] = useState([])
const [oneAircond, setoneAircond] = useState('')

const nextStep = () => {
    setStep(step + 1)
}
const prevStep = () => {
    setStep(step - 1)
}

const handleChange = input => event => {
    setInput({ [input] : event.target.value})
    console.log(input)
}

const values = { oneAircond };

return(
    <React.Fragment>
          {(() => {
                switch(step) {
                    case 1:
                        return <AircondQuantity 
                                nextStep={nextStep} 
                                handleChange = {handleChange}
                                values={values}
                                />
                    case 2:
                        return <ServicePackage 
                                nextStep={nextStep}
                                prevStep={prevStep}
                                handleChange = {handleChange}
                                values={values}
                                />
                    case 3:
                        return <Confirmation 
                                nextStep={nextStep}
                                prevStep={prevStep}
                                values={values}
                                />
                    case 4:
                    // return <Success />
                    }
            })()}
    </React.Fragment>
)
}

export default MainForm;
```

Next I transform **AirCondQuantity.jsx**, and create new component **Radio.jsx**, which holds Radio structure (it is a component into which we inject data directly)

So here is:

```
 // AircondQuantity.jsx
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, FormRadio, } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Radio from './Radio';

let AircondQuantity = (props) => {

    const [radio, setRadio] = useState();

    const radioSelect = (name, e) => {
        localStorage.setItem('FirstStep', name);
        setRadio({ selectedRadio: name })   
        console.log(radio)
      }

      const saveAndContinue = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        props.nextStep()
      }

    return(
        <Form >
        <h1 className="ui centered"> How many aircond units do you wish to service? </h1>
        <Form.Field>
        <Radio 
                            handleRadioSelect={radioSelect} 
                            selectedRadio={radio} 
                            name ="oneAircond"/>
         <Radio 
                            handleRadioSelect={radioSelect} 
                            selectedRadio={radio} 
                            name ="twoAircond"/>
        </Form.Field>
        <Button onClick={saveAndContinue}> Next </Button>
    </Form>
    )
}


export default AircondQuantity;
```

I added function, which **setting the item to LocalStorage** + **send it in radio state**

Additional here is a **Radio component**:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';

const Radio = (props) => {


    return (
        <div className = "RadioButton"
             onClick={() => props.handleRadioSelect(props.name)} >
                <div>
                        <input id={props.id} value={props.value} type="radio" checked={props.selectedRadio === props.name} />
                        {props.name}
                </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Radio;
```

The solution works, despite one thing - it doesn't check the box, I have no idea how to fix it.